# dyld: Symbol not found: Xcode 11 crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

The project was running on Xcode 9 , but I am now using Xcode 11.
Now the project runs but instantly crashes with the following error.
I tried in both simulator and device.

*The foundation framework is added.
*I did a clean install and deleted derived data as well.

> dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability.    Referenced
>   from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/85..C3/app.app/app.
>   Expected in: 
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/85..C3/app.app/Frameworks/Reachability.framework/Reachability.
>   in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/85..C3/app.app/app

PodFile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

def pods
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.44.1'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.44.1'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '4.44.1'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.4'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
    pod 'Realm', '~> 3.1.1'
    pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.1'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 5.0.0'
end

target 'app-2' do
    pods
end

target 'app' do
    pods
end

target 'ServiceExtension' do
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 5.0.0'
end

target 'LServiceExtension' do
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 5.0.0'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
    end
end
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: plus one : did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue. I believe the cause is that I'm already using `Reachability` as a cocoapod and another library (`PusherSwift`) I'm using is also using it. For some reason unknown to me, it's causing a conflict.

Right now, I just did a workaround since I still don't know the actual answer yet. I just manually copied the files I need from `PusherSwift`, instead of installing it via Cocoapods. Then, pod installed its dependencies.

For more info on my case, please see: [dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability, Xcode 11 crash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63810860/10374366)