# dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability, Xcode 11 crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I encountered the following crash only after installing the pod [PusherSwift](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-swift).

On application launch, getting a crash with the following crash logs:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability
  Referenced from: /Users/abc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/387D652C-CB80-4739-88B1-DD04ACAFA8D6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D9CEB1B3-9B9D-42E8-AFB6-8BCA056DDE1C/LalaFood-User.app/Frameworks/ChatSDK.framework/ChatSDK
  Expected in: /Users/abc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/387D652C-CB80-4739-88B1-DD04ACAFA8D6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D9CEB1B3-9B9D-42E8-AFB6-8BCA056DDE1C/LalaFood-User.app/Frameworks/Reachability.framework/Reachability
 in /Users/abc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/387D652C-CB80-4739-88B1-DD04ACAFA8D6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D9CEB1B3-9B9D-42E8-AFB6-8BCA056DDE1C/LalaFood-User.app/Frameworks/ChatSDK.framework/ChatSDK
```

I have the following [file](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/blob/master/Sources/Reachability.swift) copied directly to my project. As I checked [PusherSwift.podspec](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-swift/blob/master/PusherSwift.podspec), it has `ReachabilitySwift` as a dependency. So, I'm guessing that's where the problem came from. I tried deleting the **Reachability** [file](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/blob/master/Sources/Reachability.swift) that was directly copied on my project, but after running, the crash is still there.

I also have [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) library by Tony Million through another pod, but I have no idea which one.

I also tried implementing `PusherSwift` on a fresh new project and it works perfectly fine. But when I try on my existing project, it always crashes.

Is there something I have to import like the header file or something to add? I keep seeing to add the framework on ***Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content***. I tried to add `Reachability.framework` there, but it did not work.

Hoping someone could help.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you run `pod install` and are you opening the Xcode workspace instead of the project file? See also [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html).

Comment: Yes. I'm following the issue on the link you sent, but unfortunately, no one has still answered it. Also, using `PusherSwift` on a fresh new project works perfectly fine. But on my existing project, it's crashing.

Comment: Make sure all external frameworks are in the “Embedded Binaries” section of your Xcode target.

Comment: Is it the `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content` part? I tried to add it there, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Correct - and it should also be in BuildPhases -> Embed Frameworks.

Comment: I have tried what you said, but unfortunately, it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I just did a workaround on this. I just manually copied the files I need from `PusherSwift`, instead of installing it via Cocoapods. Then, pod installed its dependencies.